# jQuery hide() Then show() a <div> Isn't Completely Hiding the <div> on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

goal:
when page loads, slowly show a div that is not seen on page load.

current code:

```
$('h1.page_heading_title').hide().fadeIn(666);
```

issue:
when using the above code, the div fist shows on page load, then hides, then slowly fades in. this is giving users a glitchy effect.

thoughts:
is there something i am missing here to completely hide the div and then fadein()? the next solution i can think of is edit the div to `display:none`, then use `addClass()` to add a div class that uses css animations to complete my task. my only worry is that sure seems like a lot of code to do something that in theory jquery should be doing already with `.hide().fadIn()`.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just sounds like your page is taking a bit to load. Assuming you have this in a `$(document).ready()`, it won't hide the div until the page is entirely rendered. Why not just put `display: none;` on it to start instead of doing `.hide`?

Comment: yes the code is in document.ready, so that makes sense. is using css for this our only option?

Comment: If you need it hidden before document load then yes

Comment: @HollerTrain I've turned my comment into an answer to explain with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sounds like your page is taking a bit to load. Assuming you have this in a `$(document).ready()`, it won't run your JavaScript until the DOM has finished rendering.

You can ensure that the `<h1>` is hidden before loading by setting it to `display: none;`, either using inline-styling or CSS:

```js
$('h1.page_heading_title').fadeIn(666);
```

```css
h1.page_heading_title {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="page_heading_title">This is a heading.</h1>
```

Comment: i appreciate it. while i was hoping for a non-css method, i do respect what document.ready() can and cannot do.

Comment: No problem. As a general rule of thumb, you should almost always *prefer* CSS methods rather than avoid them. JavaScript should only be used for visual effects when CSS cannot achieve the desired effect on its own.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use `display:none` as style for div and then `fadeIn()` from js. no need to use `addClass()`, something like this:

```js
$('div').fadeIn(666);
```

```css
div{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>A div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply set display:none as the style of the element, then use fade in.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('h1.page_heading_title').fadeIn(666)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="page_heading_title" style="display:none">My Header</h1>
```

Comment: The answer is totally correct but the next time try to use the SO snippets functionality for code which can be executed :)

Comment: Ah thank you, didn't even notice that was an option.